# Long time before printing, no new header

Tags: vba, printing, header

I have the following code to print a specific header to each page I want to print. It takes quite some time before I can print because it regenerates over 40 sheets. Above that the project number never changes, somehow the old project number (F6) keeps in front of the new value of F6.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)


Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In Worksheets
Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture
        .Filename = "I:\Logo.png"
        .Height = 40
        .Width = 150

    End With
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G" & vbCr & "" & vbCr & "&10Project: " & Worksheets(1).Range("F6").Text
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "p. "
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Try a `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` to check that `Worksheets(1).Range("F6").Value` is changing.  Also not sure why you are using `ActiveSheet` when you could use the `WS` variable as you iterate through each sheet...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Application.PrintCommunication = False

    For Each WS In Worksheets

        With WS.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture
            .Filename = "I:\Logo.png"
            .Height = 40
            .Width = 150
        End With

        WS.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                "&10Project: " & Worksheets(1).Range("F6").Text

        WS.PageSetup.RightHeader = "p. "

    Next WS

    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```